# C# Immutable & Mutable types without duplication

Tags: c#, immutability

Given the following implementation of mutable and immutable types, **is there a way to avoid duplicate code** (mainly the duplicate properties)**?**

I'd like to work with immutable type by default unless a mutable type is required (e.g. when binding to UI elements).

We're using .NET framework 4.0, but plan switching to 4.5 soon.

```
public class Person {
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public List<string> Jobs { get; private set; } // Change to ReadOnlyList<T>
    public Person() {}
    public Person(Mutable m) {
        Name = m.Name;
    }
    public class Mutable : INotifyPropertyChanged {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<string> Jobs { get; set; }
        public Mutable() {
            Jobs = new List<string>();
        }
        public Mutable(Person p) {
            Name = p.Name;
            Jobs = new List<string>(p.Jobs);
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
            // TODO: implement
        }
    }
}

public class Consumer {
    public Consumer() {
        // We can use object initializers :)
        Person.Mutable m = new Person.Mutable {
            Name = "M. Utable"
        };
        // Consumers can happily mutate away....
        m.Name = "M. Utated";
        m.Jobs.Add("Herper");
        m.Jobs.Add("Derper");

        // But the core of our app only deals with "realio-trulio" immutable types.

        // Yey! Have constructor with arity of one as opposed to
        // new Person(firstName, lastName, email, address, im, phone)
        Person im = new Person(m);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is a question ? Not clear, honestly.

Comment: which framework you are using?

Comment: Bear in mind that a `List<string>` is mutable, and therefore your `Person` can be modified by getting the `Jobs` list any changing it. I'd recommend you to either *defensively copy* it, use a *read-only wrapper* or even the `Microsoft.Bcl.Immutable` *immutable collections*.

Comment: Yup, List<T> will be re-typed to ReadOnlyList<T> from .NET 4.5 once we switch to 4.5.

Comment: I suggest you start here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/11/13/immutability-in-c-part-one-kinds-of-immutability.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no easy way to avoid duplicate code.

What you've implemented is effectivly the `builder` pattern. The .NET `StringBuilder` class follows the same approach.

The support for immutable types in C# is a bit lacking, and could do with some language specific features to make it easier. Having to create a builder is a real pain, as you've discovred. An alternative is to have a constructor that takes all the values, but you tend to end up with the mother of all constructors, which makes the code unreadable.

Answer (score 3):

I made something that does what you ask recently (using T4 templates), so it is absolutely possible:

https://github.com/xaviergonz/T4Immutable

For example, given this:

```
[ImmutableClass(Options = ImmutableClassOptions.IncludeOperatorEquals)]
class Person {
  private const int AgeDefaultValue = 18;

  public string FirstName { get; }
  public string LastName { get; }
  public int Age { get; }

  [ComputedProperty]
  public string FullName {
    get {
      return FirstName + " " + LastName;
    }
  }
}
```

It will automatically generate for you in a separate partial class file the following:

- A constructor such as public Person(string firstName, string
  lastName, int age = 18) that will initialize the values.
- Working implementations for Equals(object other) and Equals(Person other).
  Also it will add the IEquatable interface for you. Working
  implementations for operator== and operator!=
- A working implementation of GetHashCode() A better ToString() with output such as "Person { FirstName=John, LastName=Doe, Age=21 }"
- A Person With(...) method that can be used to generate a new immutable clone with 0 or more properties changed (e.g. var janeDoe = johnDoe.With(firstName: "Jane", age: 20)

So it will generate this (excluding some redundant attributes):

```
using System;

partial class Person : IEquatable<Person> {
  public Person(string firstName, string lastName, int age = 18) {
    this.FirstName = firstName;
    this.LastName = lastName;
    this.Age = age;
    _ImmutableHashCode = new { this.FirstName, this.LastName, this.Age }.GetHashCode();
  }

  private bool ImmutableEquals(Person obj) {
    if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
    if (ReferenceEquals(obj, null)) return false;
    return T4Immutable.Helpers.AreEqual(this.FirstName, obj.FirstName) && T4Immutable.Helpers.AreEqual(this.LastName, obj.LastName) && T4Immutable.Helpers.AreEqual(this.Age, obj.Age);
  }

  public override bool Equals(object obj) {
    return ImmutableEquals(obj as Person);
  }

  public bool Equals(Person obj) {
    return ImmutableEquals(obj);
  }

  public static bool operator ==(Person a, Person b) {
    return T4Immutable.Helpers.AreEqual(a, b);
  }

  public static bool operator !=(Person a, Person b) {
    return !T4Immutable.Helpers.AreEqual(a, b);
  }

  private readonly int _ImmutableHashCode;

  private int ImmutableGetHashCode() {
    return _ImmutableHashCode;
  }

  public override int GetHashCode() {
    return ImmutableGetHashCode();
  }

  private string ImmutableToString() {
    var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    sb.Append(nameof(Person) + " { ");

    var values = new string[] {
      nameof(this.FirstName) + "=" + T4Immutable.Helpers.ToString(this.FirstName),
      nameof(this.LastName) + "=" + T4Immutable.Helpers.ToString(this.LastName),
      nameof(this.Age) + "=" + T4Immutable.Helpers.ToString(this.Age),
    };

    sb.Append(string.Join(", ", values) + " }");
    return sb.ToString();
  }

  public override string ToString() {
    return ImmutableToString();
  }

  private Person ImmutableWith(T4Immutable.WithParam<string> firstName = default(T4Immutable.WithParam<string>), T4Immutable.WithParam<string> lastName = default(T4Immutable.WithParam<string>), T4Immutable.WithParam<int> age = default(T4Immutable.WithParam<int>)) {
    return new Person(
      !firstName.HasValue ? this.FirstName : firstName.Value,
      !lastName.HasValue ? this.LastName : lastName.Value,
      !age.HasValue ? this.Age : age.Value
    );
  }

  public Person With(T4Immutable.WithParam<string> firstName = default(T4Immutable.WithParam<string>), T4Immutable.WithParam<string> lastName = default(T4Immutable.WithParam<string>), T4Immutable.WithParam<int> age = default(T4Immutable.WithParam<int>)) {
    return ImmutableWith(firstName, lastName, age);
  }

}
```

And there are some more features as explained in the project page.

PS: If you want a property that's a list of other immutable objects just add:

```
public ImmutableList<string> Jobs { get; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the properties don't have the same visibility, this is not duplicate code. If their visibilty were the same, Person could inherit from Mutable to avoid duplication. Right now, I don't think there is code to factorize in what you show.

Comment: Technically, you're right in that it is not *exactly* duplicate code. However, property definitions are done twice, and where duplication manifests. The **intent** (Name and Jobs) is written out twice, which violates DRY.

Comment: It's because you use the property for different intents. What you actually, I think, want in the Person class are methods `getName(){return mutable.Name;}` and `getJobs()...`, and perharps a private setter `setMutable()...`. This would clarify the intent and avoid duplication, but it makes bigger code. The "shortcut" you used here seems legit to me, as I still understand what you wanna do with it.

Comment: (Assuming Person has a Mutable instance): This would make Person class suddenly mutable. In words of Eric Lippert, Person then becomes *Obervational Immutable*. That is: Immutable on the outside, but on the inside still very mutable.

Comment: Person is already only obervational immutable, since it has private setters, so I thought it was not a problem.

Comment: Right. I should change the implementation to readonly backing fields with sole getters.

Answer (score 0):

Think about using code generation to map each mutable to its immutable equivalent.
I personally like T4 code generation, aided by T4Toolbox library.
You can quite easily parse your code using EnvDTE.

You can find tons of high-quality information about T4 on Oleg Sych blog
http://www.olegsych.com/

Code generation could be hard to handle in the beginning, but it solves the infamous issue of the code-that-must-be-duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

One for your consideration depending on if you're creating a public facing API is to consider 'popcicle immutability' as discussed by [Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/11/13/immutability-in-c-part-one-kinds-of-immutability.aspx). The nice thing about this is you don't need any duplication at all.

I've used something in reverse, my classes are mutable until a certain point when some calculations are going to occur at which point I call a Freeze() method. All changes to properties call a BeforeValueChanged() method, which if frozen throws an exception.

What you need is something whereby the classes are frozen by default, and you unfreeze them if you need them mutable. As others have mentioned if frozen you need to be returning read only copies of lists etc.

Here's an example of a little class I put together:

```
/// <summary>
/// Defines an object that has a modifiable (thawed) state and a read-only (frozen) state
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// All derived classes should call <see cref="BeforeValueChanged"/> before modifying any state of the object. This
/// ensures that a frozen object is not modified unexpectedly.
/// </remarks>
/// <example>
/// This sample show how a derived class should always use the BeforeValueChanged method <see cref="BeforeValueChanged"/> method.
/// <code>
/// public class TestClass : Freezable
/// {
///    public String Name
///    {
///       get { return this.name; }
///       set
///       {
///          BeforeValueChanged();
///          this.name = name;
///       }
///    }
///    private string name;
/// }
/// </code>
/// </example>
[Serializable]
public class Freezable
{
    #region Locals

    /// <summary>Is the current instance frozen?</summary>
    [NonSerialized]
    private Boolean _isFrozen;

    /// <summary>Can the current instance be thawed?</summary>
    [NonSerialized]
    private Boolean _canThaw = true;

    /// <summary>Can the current instance be frozen?</summary>
    [NonSerialized]
    private Boolean _canFreeze = true;

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a value that indicates whether the object is currently modifiable.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///   <c>true</c> if this instance is frozen; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
    /// </value>
    public Boolean IsFrozen 
    {
        get { return this._isFrozen; }
        private set { this._isFrozen = value; } 
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a value indicating whether this instance can be frozen.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///     <c>true</c> if this instance can be frozen; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
    /// </value>
    public Boolean CanFreeze
    {
        get { return this._canFreeze; }
        private set { this._canFreeze = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a value indicating whether this instance can be thawed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///   <c>true</c> if this instance can be thawed; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
    /// </value>
    public Boolean CanThaw
    {
        get { return this._canThaw; }
        private set { this._canThaw = value; }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Freeze the current instance.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="System.InvalidOperationException">Thrown if the instance can not be frozen for any reason.</exception>
    public void Freeze()
    {
        if (this.CanFreeze == false)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The instance can not be frozen at this time.");

        this.IsFrozen = true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Does a Deep Freeze for the duration of an operation, preventing it being thawed while the operation is running.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="operation">The operation to run</param>
    internal void DeepFreeze(Action operation)
    {
        try
        {
            this.DeepFreeze();
            operation();
        }
        finally
        {
            this.DeepThaw();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Applies a Deep Freeze of the current instance, preventing it be thawed, unless done deeply.
    /// </summary>
    internal void DeepFreeze()
    {
        // Prevent Light Thawing
        this.CanThaw = false;
        this.Freeze();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Applies a Deep Thaw of the current instance, reverting a Deep Freeze.
    /// </summary>
    internal void DeepThaw()
    {
        // Enable Light Thawing
        this.CanThaw = true;
        this.Thaw();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Thaws the current instance.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="System.InvalidOperationException">Thrown if the instance can not be thawed for any reason.</exception>
    public void Thaw()
    {
        if (this.CanThaw == false)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The instance can not be thawed at this time.");

        this.IsFrozen = false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Ensures that the instance is not frozen, throwing an exception if modification is currently disallowed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="System.InvalidOperationException">Thrown if the instance is currently frozen and can not be modified.</exception>
    protected void BeforeValueChanged()
    {
        if (this.IsFrozen)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Unable to modify a frozen object");
    }

    #endregion
}
```